# Using datatoc.c to make the splash screen blender 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I´ve read this:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.4/Doc/How_to/Edit_the_SplashScreen
The page points to a c conversor "datatoc.c"
I´m on Blender 2.79 at the moment, with all the source code downloaded.
I am looking into: blender-git\blender\release\datafiles and I see no datatoc.c

I see a ctodata.py and I cite from the same webpage:
*If you do use blender 2.5, than there is a python script (that supports .png files) that does this. Invoke it with:
./datatoc.py splash.png*

First: I am using this on the command line on windows 7x64:
ctodata.py splash.png

I get this error:
G:\blender-git\blender\release\datafiles>ctodata.py splash.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\blender-git\blender\release\datafiles\ctodata.py", line 47, in 
    data = [int(v) for v in data]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x89PNG'

I don´t know where to get that file "datatoc.c" to run it on the command window. It is not on the source code of blender 2.79 dependencies.
Please help.

Comment: I found a datatoc.c file on : G:\blender-git\blender\source\blender\datatoc
on a command prompt I am writting: datatoc.c splash.jpg
But nothing happens and instead windows asks me what program will open datatoc.c I pointed to visual studio community 2017 and I even tried to compile it, wouldn´t work.

Comment: ask https://discord.gg/PsaDKZa

Answer (score 2):

While this is still [considered off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/935) -

You are mixing up two similar names, you want to use `datatoc` but you are running `ctodata.py`. The page you read is out of date.

`datatoc` is a c program built as part of building blender. You can find it's source files in `source/blender/datatoc/`. When you build blender it will be in the `build/bin` folder.

Tou make use of a custom splash screen you need to build your own copy of blender, therefore the easiest way is to save your image as `release/datafiles/splash.png` and let the build process merge it into your blender.

Comment: Thank you. I'll search the datatoc.c from where you mention. Also I followed the "build and compile blender" path, effectively, placing the splash.png in it's folder and hence building blender.exe with the splash screen.